# Wrapping C .a library into xcode bundle

Tags: c, header, wrapper

I'm trying to create a wrapper for a ".a" library into an xcode bundle. Everything seems to work fine except for the importing of the library headers. The compiling process gets stuck when it encounter declarations like this in the header files:

```
 HIK_EXPORT HIKCharacter        * HIK_API HIKCharacterCreate( const HIKCharacterDefinition *pCharacterDefinition, HIKMalloc pMalloc, const char *pValidationString);
```

and the error I get is

```
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
```

I must admit that this is the first time a see a declaration like that so I don't really know what to do. 
Hope someone can help ^^
Thanks

Comment: You're missing some other header file, it seems, or you need to reorder the includes.

Comment: The header file that is giving me errors is the last one on the include list, and i included every header that library has :/

Comment: Could have been an incorrect compiler setting or preprocessor flag causing e.g. `HIK_EXPORT` to be declared incorrectly. Glad you fixed it.

Comment: Ok i fixed it, using a already prepared xcode project. Maybe i was missing some in the project settings, but sadly I don't know exactly what. Since it's working i'll live with it ^^